# Display the navigationController in a viewController presented modally

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `viewController` presented from the `appDelegate` when user receive a push notification.

My problem is that i can't find a way to display the original `navigationController` with it's `navBar` and button.

Note that my app has a `tabBarController` with 4 items, each one has his navigation controller.

```
=> navigationController A => VC1 => VC2

=> navigationController B => VC1 => VC2

navigationController => rootViewController  => tabBar

=> navigationController C => VC1 => VC2

=> navigationController D => VC1 => VC2
```

So i tried this in `viewWillAppear` but not worked :

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if self.navigationController == nil {

        let navigationController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0].rootViewController as UINavigationController

        self.navigationController == navigationController
    }

}
```

Comment: ("rootViewController as UINavigationController")  Isn't your root view controller a tab bar controller?

Comment: No i have in fact a tuto the firs time the app i opened. See my edited post.